# Strange terminal navigation when logged in as new user

Tags: 12.04, command-line, ssh, sudo, ls

I am not even sure how to ask this properly..

I am using EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 I added a new user

```
 sudo useradd -g admin admin
 sudo adduser admin sudo
```

Changed shudders so I can use new user without password then did this:

```
sudo useradd -g admin admin
sudo adduser admin sudo
sudo su admin
cd ~
sudo mkdir .ssh
sudo cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/admin/.ssh
sudo chown admin:admin /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now when I ssh in as admin I get strange terminal behavior:

1) I can't ls

2) Pressing arrow up results in ^[[A

How can I fix it and why it happened??

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because you used `useradd` instead off `adduser` to make the new user. On Ubuntu by default `useradd` sets the user's default shell to `/bin/sh` (`dash`), while `adduser` sets it to `/bin/bash`. And `/bin/sh` doesn't have `readline` support, hence the unexpected behaviour with the up arrow.

You just have to switch to `bash` by typing in `bash`.

To change the new user's default shell to `bash` use:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

while logged in as the new user (`admin`).

Comment: At least for the up arrow behaviour. Why you can't `ls`? I now have no clue.

Comment: I ended up deleting the user I just created. The process was `useradd newuser`, `userdel newuser`, `adduser newuser` while logged in as root. Just in case anyone needs a quick fix.